# Why does the following code return the error message The type Person is already defined. What is the issue with the Class Person?

Tags: java, eclipse, class

Why does the following code return the error message The type Person is already defined. What is the issue with the class Person?

```
class Person {
   String name;
   int age;

   void speak() {
       System.out.println("Hellp there " + name);
   }
   void calcuateYearsToRetirement() {
       int yearsleft = 65 - age;
       System.out.println("You have " + yearsleft + " until you can retire!");
   }
}


public class GettersAndReturners {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Person person1 = new Person();

       person1.name = "Taylor Attix";
       person1.age = 15;
       person1.calcuateYearsToRetirement();


    } 

}
```

Also if it helps this is the error message Eclipse returns is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: Person.calcuateYearsToRetirement()V
at GettersAndReturners.main(GettersAndReturners.java:29)
```

Comment: @DnR The default constructor is being used.

Comment: @arshajii ah of course!

Comment: Also, *calcuate* should probably be spelled *calculate*.

Comment: "Hello" is also misspelled in `speak()`, but that isn't giving you errors, just triggering my OCD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely problem is that you are using a version of `Person` class that does not have method `calcuateYearsToRetirement()`. If you have added the method recently, then try to compile your `Person` class again and then recompile your `GettersAndReturners` class to use the right version of `Person` class.